# How to implement IOS Siri for text to speech in IOS application?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

Is there any way to implement the IOS Siri's voice into my ios application for text to speech conversion? I want to implement the same voice as the Siri has.

Could be possible to convert text to voice with Siri using SWIFT language or anything?

I have already implement this one but the voice is not like Siri's has, its looking like computer's voice.

```
        import AVFoundation

        class ViewController: UIViewController {

            let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                let voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")

                let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello, this is Siri's voice.")
                utterance.voice = voice

                synthesizer.speak(utterance)
            }
        }
```